# Android app connection from external network

Tags: android, postgresql, android-studio, database-connection, ubuntu-server

I have an android app programmed using android studio that is properly working in my local network. How do I have to do to make the app usable from users connecting from outside (for example using a 3G connection for login to my ubuntu server and making connections to my postgreSQL database from outside my network)? I do have a static IP address and the ports open. This is the final step I have to solve before publishing the app making it available to the general public.

Answer (score 1):

You should not connect directly to your database from an app.  The reason-  you'd need to put the password in your app.  That's insecure-  anyone can decompile your app and have full access to your database.  Instead you should use webservices-  your app talks to a webservice on your server, which talks to the database.  This way the password doesn't need to leave your hardware.